# Этимология слова "настигать"

Tags: этимология

Что за происхождение у слова "настигать"?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61174/discussion-on-question-by-andrejj2133---).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От слова "стега" – шаг, а потом и тропинка, дорожка. Позарастали стёжки-дорожки... Вспомним, что и сейчас стёжка или стежок – "шаг" иглы. Первоначально настигать – догонять пешком, шагами. Лев Успенский приводит областное слово "достогнать" с тем же значением.